# Implement global variables in Polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to replicate the example in the following section of the Polymer 0.5 docs, which uses the MonoState pattern to implement global variables in Polymer:

http://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#global

I'm trying to get this working using Polymer 1.0 but am not having much luck.

Here is my code for the `app-globals` and `my-component` custom elements. It's the same as in the above link apart from the slightly different syntax in Polymer 1.0. e.g. using `dom-module` instead of `polymer-element`.

```
<dom-module name="app-globals">
    <script>
        (function() {
            // these variables are shared by all instances of app-globals
            var values = {
                firstName: 'John',
                lastName: 'Smith'
            }

            Polymer({
                 is: 'app-globals',
                ready: function() {
                    // make global values available on instance.
                    this.values = values;
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module name="my-component">
    <template>
        <app-globals id="globals"></app-globals>
        <div id="firstname">{{$.globals.values.firstName}}</div>
        <div id="lastname">{{$.globals.values.lastName}}</div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
             is: 'my-component',
              ready: function() {
                console.log('Last name: ' + this.$.globals.values.lastName);
              }
    });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

The usage is simply:

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

Initially I was encountering the error "Cannot read property '$' of undefined". So I replaced the `div` content `$.globals.values.firstName` with `this.$.globals.values.firstName` (and similarly for the `lastName` field) in the `my-component` custom element.

However the divs are not displaying the first and last names. It looks like `this.$.globals.values.firstName` and `this.$.globals.values.lastName` are not set when the div's are rendered.

Would appreciate some help to resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried `this.set('values', values);` instead of `this.values = values;`? Does `console.log()` print the values? Also have a look at https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta that does what your element is supposed to do.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I wasn't aware of the iron-meta element. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `<dom-module id="app-globals">` I think you can catch these errors if you use polylint (https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polylint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is working example, [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/f3Ia4wFz2GeaAzkNceL7?p=preview)

```
properties: {
          values: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true
          }
        },

        ready: function() {
          // make global values available on instance.
          this.values = {
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Smith'
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this has resolved the issue so marking as correct answer. I will also look into the iron-meta element as an alternative approach.